# QGIS not opening NetCDF File correctly

Tags: qgis, scale

I am trying to add a NetCDF file of sea ice age into QGIS (have tried by raster, drop and drop, mesh), the .nc file contains the sea ice age, latitude and longitude. When I by adding by raster it asks which layer I want to add out the the three so I select sea ice age however it does not project it to my current map scale - it only appears very very small and therefore unusable. Why is this happening?

This is my .nc data source: https://daacdata.apps.nsidc.org/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0611_seaice_age_v4/data/

Comment: Sometimes netcdf's do not have their projection info stored in a way that QGIS understands. You may have to edit it. - check this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379701/mapping-a-netcdf-in-qgis-in-the-correct-location-on-earth?rq=1 and this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195627/opening-chirps-netcdf-file-in-qgis?rq=1 Also try just setting the correct projection of the layer in the layer properties.

Comment: this is likely not yet supported in MDAL,see https://github.com/lutraconsulting/MDAL/issues/372